# Apache Sedona Version Issues

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, geospatial, apache-sedona

So I'm trying to set up Apache Sedona but running into strange issues that suggest that the version compatibilities are off. For context, I have Apache version 1.5.1, PySpark version 3.2.1, and Scala 2.12.18.

I installed the below packages using maven.

I'm trying to run this code

```
from sedona.spark import *

spark = SedonaContext.builder().\
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.4_2.12:1.5.1,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.5.1-28.2,'
           'uk.co.gresearch.spark:spark-extension_2.12:2.11.0-3.4,'
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-python-adapter-3.0_2.12:1.4.1'). \
    config('spark.jars.repositories', 'https://artifacts.unidata.ucar.edu/repository/unidata-all'). \
    getOrCreate()

sedona = SedonaContext.create(spark)
```

according to their example notebook https://github.com/apache/sedona/blob/master/binder/ApacheSedonaSQL.ipynb, but also making sure to add in the Python Adapter.

But I get this error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o206.showString.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'double org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate.getZ()'
    at org.apache.sedona.common.geometrySerde.GeometrySerializer.getCoordinateType(GeometrySerializer.java:449)
    at org.apache.sedona.common.geometrySerde.GeometrySerializer.serializePoint(GeometrySerializer.java:112)
    at org.apache.sedona.common.geometrySerde.GeometrySerializer.serialize(GeometrySerializer.java:43)
    at org.apache.sedona.sql.utils.GeometrySerializer$.serialize(GeometrySerializer.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.expressions.implicits$GeometryEnhancer.toGenericArrayData(implicits.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.expressions.InferredTypes$.$anonfun$buildSerializer$1(InferredExpression.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sedona_sql.expressions.InferredExpression.eval(InferredExpression.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnaryExpression.eval(Expression.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConstantFolding$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.applyOrElse(expressions.scala:69)
```

which seems like the Geo tools are not working. I can load a regular dataframe though, just can't do geospatial operations on them. What's the issue here?

Comment: Are you including the jts jar?

Comment: Yea when I include the JTS 19.0 jar, I still get the same issue

Comment: Looks like its been there for 6+ years https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blame/f568af79876a8c7a359ae10fd0ff5b9d62634a27/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Coordinate.java#L189 - when you say the jar you do mean jts-core?

Comment: Yup, `'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.19.0,'` specifically